# Make [karma] a synonym of [karma-runner]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Currently there are two tags used for questions related to Karma (JavaScript Test Runner):

- [karma-runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karma-runner)
- [karma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/karma)

Description of both of these tags is the same project (even though the actual text is slightly different):

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/karma-runner/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/karma/info

I think it would be better to use "karma-runner" as "karma" is too general. However, I'm fine with either way.

**UPDATE:**
Right now, I can't suggest `karma` to be a synonym of `karma-runner`, because there are more questions with `karma` tag.
I can't suggest `karma-runner`to be a synonym of `karma` either, because `karma-runner` already has a synonym (`testacular`), which is a valid synonym as that is a former name of the project.

**UPDATE:**
I renamed about 20 tags and then I was able to suggest the synonym. So please vote:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/karma-runner/synonyms

Comment: Why don't you suggest `karma` as a [synonym for `karma-runner`](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/karma-runner/synonyms) instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that sounds about right, I'm updating the title. I didn't know about synonyms.

Comment: I can't suggest `karma` to be a synonym of `karma-runner` because there are more questions with `karma` tag. I can't do it the other way around either, as `testacular` is already a synonym of `karma-runner`.

Comment: Is there any way somebody can remove the "testacular" synonym of "karma-runner" so that we can make both "testacular" and "karma-runner" synonyms of "karma"? Sounds like that would be the best solution...

Answer (score 5):

**Vojta**, since [you are the main commiter and maintainer](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/graphs/contributors) of the Karma/Karma-runner I think we follow your idea here.

As discussed in the comments above I think also `Karma-Runner` should be the right/default/main name.

I don't know if we manage all Karma questions renamed to `Karma-Runner` (I will get onto some now) but in the meantime `Karma` as synonym to `Karma-Runner` seems the best.

So lets keep `Karma-Runner` as the original/default tag.